# How to fix bluetooth mouse that has stopped working latest ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse that is paired to my laptop and has been working perfectly with ubuntu. Recently following one of the updates it remains as a paired device but will not connect.

I have removed the device and repaired but still no luck.
This is what bluetoothctl shows:

```
bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller 4C:34:88:2D:E4:CE HP-ENVY-Notebook [default]
[NEW] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 BluetoothMouse3600
Agent registered

[bluetooth]# devices
Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 BluetoothMouse3600

[bluetooth]# scan on
[NEW] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 BluetoothMouse3600

bluetooth]# pair E8:A1:FB:14:98:93
Attempting to pair with E8:A1:FB:14:98:93
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 Connected: yes
[NEW] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_A1_FB_14_98_93/service0008
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Generic Attribute Profile
[NEW] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_A1_FB_14_98_93/service0009
    0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Device Information
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_A1_FB_14_98_93/service0009/char000a
    00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Manufacturer Name String
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_A1_FB_14_98_93/service0009/char000c
    00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    PnP ID
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 UUIDs: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 UUIDs: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 UUIDs: 00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 Modalias: usb:v045Ep0916d0100
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 Connected: no

[bluetooth]# trust E8:A1:FB:14:98:93
[CHG] Device E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 Trusted: yes
Changing E8:A1:FB:14:98:93 trust succeeded

[bluetooth]# connect E8:A1:FB:14:98:93
Attempting to connect to E8:A1:FB:14:98:93
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Some Interesting Syslog Entries:

```
bluetoothd[3564]: Write report characteristic descriptor failed: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error 
bluetoothd[3564]: Failed to connection details: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107) 
bluetoothd[3564]: Write report characteristic descriptor failed: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed blueman

"apt-get install blueman"

then removed the device and added it back in blueman manager

"/usr/bin/blueman-manager"

strange that this worked when adding directly using gnome interface didn't but happy that it did :-)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with a confused MX Keys on 20.04. I didn't have to remove and re-add, just find it in the list in blueman and pick Connect from the RMB menu.

Comment: Man, I lost one hour to understand why my mouse stopped to work. Installed blueman, launched blueman-tray, and it connected straight away. (Logitech MX Vertical) It worked for months until this morning, when it started to lag, and finally disconnected. Hope that this will save some other's time. Cheers